# OpenSSH (Windows) to SSH (Linux) key auth not working

Tags: ssh, openssh

I've setup an OpenSSH server on my windows machine and have been able to successfully SSH from windows box to my Linux machine (and vice-versa) successfully.

Although, I am not able to set up key authentication for the same... here are the steps that I followed

**On Windows - OpenSSH**

```
C:\OpenSSH\bin> ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/Arpit/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/Arpit/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/Arpit/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
b9:0c:33:15:9f:8a:bf:02:cf:80:43:7c:6e:42:07:52 Arpit@Windows-HOST

C:\OpenSSH\bin> scp "C:\Documents and Settings\Arpit\.ssh\id_rsa.pub" Arpit@Linux-HOST:
```

Tried ssh after these steps but it was asking password to connect

**On Linux**

```
[arpit@Linux-HOST ~]$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/arpit/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/arpit/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/arpit/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
e8:ac:43:a5:52:d5:ca:11:ea:2f:ae:b9:b0:cb:ba:8e arpit@Linux-HOST
[arpit@Linux-HOST ~]$ ssh-copy-id -i /home/arpit/.ssh/id_rsa.pub arpit@Windows-HOST
arpit@Windows-HOST's password:
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'arpit@Windows-HOST'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

Still no luck. Can anybody help me with the same?

Comment: It might just be asking for the passphrase to decrypt the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like apart from the user directory (`C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\.ssh`) directory, we need to copy the `authorized_keys` file to the following location:

`[OpenSSH Installation Directory]\etc\`

Key authentication started working once I copied the remote host's public keys at the above mentioned location.

Answer (score 2):

Have you copied the public key into authorized_key file in your linux machine?:

Open the "C:\Documents and Settings\Arpit.ssh\id_rsa.pub" file with notepad, copy the content and append to .ssh/authorized_key in your Linux machine. Then try again

Comment: Yes, did it. Still asking for password :(

Answer (score 2):

On my client (windows) i had an wrong `id_rsa.pub` file in my `~/.ssh/` folder.

After I deleted this file the public key authentication worked just fine.

I found this solution here: https://superuser.com/a/1067189/724897

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone hits the same error as me. If you save your id_rsa key with notepad it will be a txt file, and openssh won't find it. To remedy this open id_rsa, save as, all types, and then give it the name "id_rsa" **with the quotes**. This saves it without an extension an openssh likes you again.