# SSH-Key authentication fails

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-keys

I'm trying to ssh into a CentOS server which I have no control over.. the admin has added my public key to the server and insists the fault lies with me but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Config in .ssh:

```
tim@tim-UX31A:~$ cat ~/.ssh/config
User root
PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Permission on my key-files:

```
tim@tim-UX31A:~$ ls -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa*
-rw------- 1 tim tim 3326 Okt 20 17:28 /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 tim tim  746 Okt 20 17:28 /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Connection log which I can't make any sense of:

```
tim@tim-UX31A:~$ ssh -vvv root@10.0.12.28
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/tim/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.0.12.28" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.12.28 [10.0.12.28] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.0.12.28:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/tim/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/tim/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.12.28
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: 
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/tim/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/tim/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.12.28
debug1: Host '10.0.12.28' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/tim/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55ee619ab2b0), explicit, agent
debug2: key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55ee619bcfa0), agent
debug2: key: tim@Tim-UX31A-Debian (0x55ee619b9370), agent
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: tim@Tim-UX31A-Debian
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Comment: From the lids, it looks like the key is sent, but no response is ever received. -Are you supposed to log in as root, or do you log in as tim and then use sudo? Sometimes ssh login as root is disabled.
-What are the permissions of the .ssh directory itself?
-Do you have the right server? Is dns resolving properly?
-You could make the keys again, and then use ssh-copy-id to manually copy the new public key to the authorized_keys file. Just in case the key got corrupt somehow.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! permissions on my .ssh folder are:                  drwx------  2 tim  tim  4096 Okt 20 22:13 .ssh. Loggin in as root is correct - it actually worked a couple of weeks ago before I reformatted my computer. The admin says he has added the new keys correctly but I really don't know how it could be my fault at this point

Comment: As @KyleH mentioned, have you tried with `ssh tim@10.0.12.28` as the log mentions Kerberos the CentOS server could be Domain Integrated (AD, IPA, ...). You have to find out what user you are supposed to use. Ask the administrator. We for example are using IPA so we enable users to connect to certain servers with their IPA domain account and key pair and if necessary they can sudo. No root access :)

Answer (score 76):

This will usually resolve most SSH authorized key permission issues *on the server side*, assuming someone didn't make additional changes to the permissions.

```bash
# paste these into an SSH session that server (probably from
# another user account or root)

# change this to YOUR username on the server.
YOURUSER=example

# paste these lines verbatim:
sudo chown $YOURUSER:$YOURUSER /home/$YOURUSER/{.,.ssh/,.ssh/authorized_keys}
sudo chmod u+rwX,go-rwX,-t /home/$YOURUSER/{.ssh/,.ssh/authorized_keys}
sudo chmod go-w /home/$YOURUSER/
```

(This is what [Userify](https://userify.com) does automatically in its "shim" script to update and fix any permission issues based on changes in the team's web dashboard.)

If your admin created the .ssh/ directory or .ssh/authorized_keys file as root (which is most commonly how this becomes broken), then having the file owned by another user isn't allowed, EVEN if that user is *root*.

Comment: If this were the problem, the client wouldn't have tried to send the key to the server in the first place; the log given in the question is explicit that it does.

Comment: This corrects the server side issue. You are correct that the client side is ok.

Comment: This finally solved my problem. Spent hours trying to figure out why my public/private keys weren't being accepted.

Comment: Ugh -- what a silly error. This fixed my issue after hours of searching, thanks.

Comment: This seems like more than should need to be done. What if people don't want to change the ownership and permissions for everything in their home directory?

Comment: I had to `chmod g-w $username` as well. Because of a mistyped `rsync` command the home dir itself got group writable. That too must not be.

Comment: @HolgerBöhnke great point, added that.

Comment: Nice, that looks good. One small remark, the users home usually has `755` (`drwxr-xr-x`). For ssh to work it simply must not have `w` for group and other. So a separate chown might be less intrusive: `chmod go-w /home/$UN`. This just removes the `w` from group and other, on the home dir itself. The above command quite correctly does not change the homedir itself, because there's no dot `.` within the braces. If it would, it would remove `rx` from the homedir as well, which probably is not desired.

Comment: @HolgerBöhnke another great point, added that too.

Comment: Thanks this also fixed my problem (I wasted hours this time). And yes, my client was sending keys and the server was answering with `packet: type 51` @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 28):

I had the exact same problem on two servers: a Linux running Debian stretch and on a NAS (Synology DS715)

it turned out that in both cases, the home directory permissions on the server were wrong

the auth.log on the server was very helpful

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/cyril
```

on the Linux, it had the write/group bit on (drwxrwxr--x), so I had to remove at least the write on group (chmod g-w ~/) and then it worked

on the Synology, for whatever reason, there was a sticky bit

```
drwx--x--x+ 4 toto users 4096 Jan 6 12:11 /var/services/homes/toto
```

I had to change it with

```
chmod -t ~/
```

and I could then connect without a password

Comment: Thanks for that `chmod -t`... I ended up with:
```admin@SYN:~$ ls -ald . .ssh .ssh/*
drwxr-xr-x 6 admin users 4096 Jan 10 15:54 .
drwx------ 2 admin users 4096 Jan 10 15:54 .ssh
-rwx------ 1 admin users  401 Jan 10 15:54 .ssh/authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 admin users 1679 Jan 10 15:49 .ssh/id_rsa
-rwxr--r-- 1 admin users  396 Jan 10 15:49 .ssh/id_rsa.pub
-rwx------ 1 admin users  396 Jan 10 10:04 .ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Great suggestion.  RedHat users can look at this file: `/var/log/secure`

Comment: How to disable sshd strict checking "bad ownership or modes for file"?

Comment: @CSQGB : this is done via the "StrictModes" parameter (man sshd_config)

Comment: on ubuntu, I could debug following your answer and checking `sudo tail -n100 /var/log/auth.log` - thanks! (my problem was having wrong permissions on a drive)

Answer (score 25):

When using CentOS 7, and I'm confident applies to other Linux OS's using sshd as well. With root access, you can determine more about why authentication may be failing. To do this:

1. Enable logging for the `sshd` daemon: `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Under logging uncomment:

```bash
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
```

1. Change `LogLevel` from `INFO` to `DEBUG`
2. Save and exit
3. Restart the SSH daemon with `sudo systemctl restart sshd`
4. Watch the messages file `tail -l /var/log/messages`
5. Using another terminal, attempt to connect with ssh
6. Attempt to connect with `ssh`
7. Review the authentication log for the exact cause

For example, I was experiencing some of the same problems as mentioned above.

```
Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for file /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Using these steps I was able to confirm the problem was permissions on the `authorized_keys` file. By setting `chmod 644` on the `authorized_keys` file of my user, the problem was fixed.

Comment: This works for identifing the error, thanks.
but to solve I've to set permissions as folow:
#chmod g-w /home/your_user
#chmod 700 /home/your_user/.ssh
#chmod 600 /home/your_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
as describet here: https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/

Comment: Thanks ! Why the hell sshd does not show these important errors, except when in DEBUG ??

Comment: On a system with `journalctl -e` logging, look there instead of `/var/log/messages`. Also, on my Fedora box, I found selinux was blocking the access `sshd` needed and I had to run `sudo restorecon -FRv ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I've not looked into how this is supposed to work for all defined users by default. My problem occurred after an upgrade to a more recent Fedora version.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like the permissions on your `.ssh` folder didn't copy+paste correctly. Could you please add it again?

If strict mode is enabled then we have to make sure `.ssh` has the correct permissions of:

- `.ssh/` should have perms `0700/rwx------`
- `.ssh/*.pub` files should be `644/rw-r--r--`
- `.ssh/*` (other files in .ssh) `0600/rw-------`

How do things look for you permission-wise?

Comment: Permissions on my home folder (tim) are 755 (drwxr-xr-x) and permissions on the .ssh folder itself are 700 (drwx). id_rsa is 600 and .pub file is 644 .. :/ thanks again, hope the info helps

Comment: I have ssh working to many servers. My home directory is drwxr-xr-x (0755), .ssh is rwx------ (0700), inside .ssh my pub key is -rw-r--r-- (0644), and the rest in that folder are -rw------- (0600). So, your permissions are good and it should pass Strict Host checking.
  What is in your /etc/ssh_config file? Anything in ~/.ssh/config?
  I have had ssh key creation for one reason or another not work even though there were no errors. Can you try using ssh-keygen to regenerate your keys, ssh-copy-id to copy your pub key to the remote server that has password authentication turned on?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the server but I will try to get the admin to copy my pub key to the server again on monday.. I copied the contents of the config files to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/eEaVMcvt - thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy to help! I also enjoy problem solving and especially helping others with Linux. There is one odd line in your ssh-config that could cause issues where it's at. What is the ip 10.0.12.28?

Comment: @KyleH is right.. that's almost certainly the issue. I added another answer that shows how to fix it with root access. If you control your homedir, you can possibly fix it yourself, but of course you'd have to be able to log in :)

Comment: Tim, also just realized what @KyleH was pointing out... if you are trying to log in as root to 10.0.12.28, then that's probably the cause of your breakage (and also a net negative from a security perspective). Often /etc/ssh/sshd_config disallows root login as well. If you comment out that line, you'll log in as your regular username instead, and then you can sudo to root.

Comment: From the log in the question, the key is loaded into the OP's agent -- if permissions were bad, they wouldn't have been able to load it (and the filesystem permissions aren't rechecked when sending an agent-based key, so that couldn't possibly be the issue).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy perms on the server-side, not client.

Comment: @KyleH thank you so much, this led me to success after sucking with it all the day...

Answer (score 9):

I've had [a similar problem](https://superuser.com/a/1067189/407810), where the ssh connection tries key `~/.ssh/id_rsa` before unexpectedly stopping on:

```
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
```

In my case, it was due to an old public key file lying around in the `.ssh` directory:

```
[gitlab-runner@validation-k8s-1 ~]$ ll .ssh/id_rsa*
total 16
-rw------- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 1675 Sep 18 18:02 id_rsa      --> new private key
-rw-r--r--. 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner  423 Jun 12 13:51 id_rsa.pub --> old public key
```

Moving/deleting the `id_rsa.pub` from the `.ssh` directory solved the problem.

From what I understand: when there is a public key present on the client-side, SSH 1st validates the private key against it. If it fails, it won't try to use the private key to connect remotely.

I sent an e-mail to the openssh mailing list: https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2016-April/035048.html.

Comment: Yeaaahhhh. SERIOUSLY! I would never have look at that. `openssh-8.0p1-5.fc30.x86_64` btw. I had the public key from the earlier server with the same name as the new one lying around, `fedora@(baloo).sshkey.pub`, which goes with `fedora@(baloo).sshkey` passed on the command line with the `-i` option. Authentication failed with the new server key found in the new `fedora@(baloo).sshkey` - an RSA key.

Comment: I looked it up, packet type 51 is defined as 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE' (per rfc 4250).

Answer (score 9):

Also encountered this problem. setroubleshoot did not seem to work in my environment so there were no such log record in /var/log/messages.
Disabling SELinux was not an option for me, so I did

```
restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh
```

After that login by rsa key worked fine.

Comment: Nice. Using restorecon is the right way to fix selinux-related problems. Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/849631/why-is-selinux-blocking-remote-ssh-access-without-a-password for related troubleshooting steps

Comment: thank you, nothing above but this one worked for me

Comment: +1 This simple answer did the trick in my case

Answer (score 7):

Just in case this also saves someone. I was trying to copy a key from my Ubuntu 18.04 Machine to 2 CentOS 7 Servers. I used `ssh-copy-id` to transfer them. One worked, one didn't. So I went through all the permissions debugging and found nothing. So finally I pulled up the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on both servers and stepped line by line through them. Finally I found it, probably something that someone modified long before I got on the job.

One read:
`AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys`

And another read:
`AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, which was on the server that wasn't accepting my keys. Obviously looking between the two files and noting the comment that states the default search patterns do not include the leading `~/` I removed it and restarted sshd. Problem solved.

Additionally alternative path to key of user "Megatron" (which have home directory "/usr/sap/Earth") can be written in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" like

`AuthorizedKeysFile /home/Megatron/.ssh/authorized_keys

And even if you make new keys in your home directory with correct permissions they wouldn't work, because you forget this custom path to keys.

Comment: Just a note.  If you're going to hard code a custom authorized key file, do it in a section for that user, OR, better yet, in a file ~/.ssh/config, which overrides /etc/ssh/ssh_config.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this answer - none of the recommendations worked in my scenario. In the end, the problem was that I had created an account with no password set. Once I set the password using `usermod -p "my password" username` and then forcibly unlocked the account `usermod -U username` everything was peachy.

Comment: Your answer flagged me to my different, but also user-related, case of my trying to log in when the home directory I had given was more nested than the one I was logging in with... Great to have fixed, thanks!

Comment: this solved my issue pushing to gitea after setting `UsePAM no` in `/etc/sshd_config`

Answer (score 2):

The reason in my case was a customly set option `AuthorizedKeysFile` in file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. It was set to another user's home dir (`/home/webmaster/.ssh/authorized_keys`), so the user I was trying to log in had no access to that file/directory.

After changing it and restarting ssh-server (`service ssh restart`) everything came back to normal. I can log in by my private key now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `ssh -vvv my_dev_box` gives me this,

```
...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/userxyz/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:FzMfrbORgYEtcIaWYg2iZOBctxYeNZ9bz/vFxLLtefw agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
...
```

the `/var/log/auth.log` on the remote machine has this,

```
Invalid user userxyz from 10.11.50.126 port 50310
```

So solution is,

```
ssh correct_username@my_dev_box
```

Or you can specify the username in ssh config file.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had this issue and sometimes the answer is really that simple.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this problem.
Permissions and ownership on .ssh files were all correct.
In /var/log/messages we found:

```
Mar 29 15:45:36 centos70 setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/sshd from read access on the file authorized_keys. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 05963b94-f318-4615-806c-b6c3a9066c82
```

SO, solution for developer vm where we do not care about security is disable selinux. Edit /etc/sysconfig/selinux and change SELINUX=disabled and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issues was with the incorrect shell exec.

```
journalctl -f
....
Feb 25 11:45:54 59a02b89e0f6 sshd[]: User user not allowed because shell /usr/bin/env /bin/bash does not exist
....
```

Changed /etc/passwd file for that user

```
vi /etc/passwd 
....
user:x:1000:1000::/home/user:/bin/bash
....
```

Comment: I got similar error: `User xxx not allowed because shell fish does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

In our case the issues was related to the fact that our firewall and NATing rules were not setup correctly.

port 22, was being directed to the incorrect server where our keys and user was not being recognised.

If some one gets to this point. tcpdump and telnet can be your friend

```
[aaron@aaron-pc ~]$ telnet someserver 22
Trying 1.1.1.1...
Connected to someserver.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1
^]
telnet> 

[aaron@aaron-pc ~]$ telnet someotherserver 22
Trying 1.1.1.2...
Connected to someotherserver.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
^]
```

You will notice that these two servers have different openssh versions. 
This helped me spot the problem pretty quickly. If your hosts are using the same ssh versions you will have to try doing a packed trace on the destination to see
if traffic is actual arriving at the destination.

Ssh can generate a lot of traffic which makes tcpdump out put difficult to find what you are looking for.

This helped me

```
 tcpdump -i any  "not host [mylocalip] and not localhost and not ip and not arp"
```

Try to telnet from a 3 different server not your current computer @ [mylocalip].
You want to see what traffic actually reaches your server.

Answer (score 0):

A client-side error log ending like this:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@x.x.x.x's password:
```

can be caused by a server-side (remote) restriction on *root* login when the *sshd* configuration file contains:

```
PermitRootLogin: no
```

JonCav's suggestion to enable logging was helpful in debugging such an issue.  While client-side debug spew was remarkably unhelpful, placing the following in the *sshd* server's *sshd_config* file:

```
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG
```

ended up producing helpful log messages:

```
Jul 19 19:16:38 500265-web1 sshd[21188]: Found matching RSA key: ...
Jul 19 19:16:38 500265-web1 sshd[21188]: ROOT LOGIN REFUSED FROM ...
Jul 19 19:16:38 500265-web1 sshd[21188]: Failed publickey for root from ... port ... ssh2
Jul 19 19:16:38 500265-web1 sshd[21189]: ROOT LOGIN REFUSED FROM ...
```

In the case where only *root* login fails, and providing that using only key-based authentication for root login is permitted by your security policy, a change to the *sshd_config* file can help:

```
 PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Your mileage may vary, though this does often help, some other configuration may still interfere according to a comment found in some *sshd_config* files:

```
# Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
```

Even if you cannot easily change the remote server configuration to debug in this manner, one may proof the client-side configuration to some extent by using the same identity files to *ssh* to a non-root account on the same remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I can see why security can bother people. I just had the `ssh won't use my key` problem again.  I solved it by logging into the remote server and running

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -sDp 23456
```

and then from my desktop, (trying to ssh to server)

```
ssh -vvvv server -p 23456
```

On the server I got `Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /`

Some new sysadmin had messed up the permission and ownership, which I fixed with:

```
chmod 0755 / ; chown root:root /
```

(I'm used to needing `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/* ; chmod 0644 ~/.ssh/*.pub` but sshd checking/finding the root permissions is a new one for me.) Now I'm going to check for a rootkit and then wipe and re-install anyway.

Comment: How to disable sshd strict checking "bad ownership or modes for file"?

Comment: You don't. You correct the ownership modes with with chmod.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on CentOS 7. I am a regular Debian-based Linux user so I was a fish out of the water. I noticed that in some of the servers it worked and in just one it didn't. The audit.log said nothing useful and the secure.log did not give anything either.
I found that the only real difference was some security context differences on files and directories between those that worked and those that didn't. Get the security with

`sudo ls -laZ <user-home>/.ssh`

of the directory (I'm assuming a lot of defaults on sshd_config).

You should see some `ssh_home_t` and `user_home_t` attributes. If you don't, use the `chcon` command to add the missing attributes.

For example

```
home="$(getent passwd <user> | cut -d: -f6)"
sudo chcon -R unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 "$home".ssh
sudo chcon unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 "$home"
```

In my case, my suspicion is that the user was created in a non standard way. His home was a directory in `/var/lib`.

More info in: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/selinux-preventing-ssh-login-with-~-ssh-authorized_keys-4175469538/

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this can fail is if the `authorized_keys` or `administrators_authorized_keys` was edited by notepad.exe or similar and the encoding was set to something stupid like UTF-16.

In that case, use notepad to Save As UTF-8 (not UTF-8 with BOM) and save as type All Files.