# Permission denied (publickey) with error message: receive packet: type 51

Tags: ssh-keys

I can log into all Ubuntu instances with `gcp` using the same SSH keys, except for one instance, with the Admin creating a user for me, adding me to the `sudo` and `admin` groups, adding my pub key there as well, but I still cannot log in via `ssh myname@ip`, nor via the `gcp` SSH command, with the error message always being `Permission denied (publickey)`.

- I compared debug info of `ssh -vvvv myname@IP` with logs from other instances I can access, finding the difference at line 97:

  - IP I *cannot* log into: `debug3: receive packet: type 51`
  - IP I *can* log into: `receive packet: type 60`

  ```
   73 debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
   74 debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:gbz... explicit agent
   75 debug1: Will attempt key: myname@myname RSA SHA256:ge3... agent
   76 debug1: Will attempt key: myname@myname RSA SHA256:Ckn... agent
   77 debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
   78 debug3: send packet: type 5
   79 debug3: receive packet: type 7
   80 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
   81 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
   82 debug3: receive packet: type 6
   83 debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
   84 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
   85 debug3: send packet: type 50
   86 debug3: receive packet: type 51
   87 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
   88 debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
   89 debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
   90 debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
   91 debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
   92 debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
   93 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   94 debug1: Offering public key: /Users/myname/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:gbz... explicit agent
   95 debug3: send packet: type 50
   96 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply

   97 debug3: receive packet: type 51

   98 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
   99 debug1: Offering public key: myname@myname RSA SHA256:ge3... agent
  100 debug3: send packet: type 50
  101 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
  102 debug3: receive packet: type 51
  103 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
  104 debug1: Offering public key: myname@myname RSA SHA256:Ckn... agent
  105 debug3: send packet: type 50
  106 debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
  107 debug3: receive packet: type 51
  108 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
  109 debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  110 debug1: No more authentication methods to try.

  111         myname@myname@ip: Permission denied (publickey).
  ```

Does anybody know why I cannot log into the IP due to `type 51`, and should I re-create `id_rsa` key-pair; if so, will I be able to log into other instances, as other instances are using my current `id_rsa` key without any issue and I am unsure if re-creating it will create a new issue?

- I have three pairs of keys within my local machine's `~/.ssh` [`id_rsa`, `google_compute_engine`, `google_compute_engine2`] and for debugging purposes, I asked the Admin to add all the pub keys to that instance (even if `id_rsa` has a problem, the other two should have been workable, and am unsure why none work)

Comment: Check the answers here https://superuser.com/questions/1137438/ssh-key-authentication-fails/1145465